# How does one specify directory, permissions, and create sub-directory for S3 in AWS lambda code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda

I am implementing an AWS lambda function
(JavaScript, node.js environment)
which uses a call which goes like this:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');

const s3  = new aws.S3();

function work1(obj, cb_Work1) {
    console.log(">>> Calling work");

    s3.putObject({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: 'test.txt',
        Body: JSON.stringify(obj)
    })
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('S3 -> UPLOAD SUCCESS');
        work2(obj, (resp) => {
            cb_Work1(resp);
        });
    })

    .catch(e => {
        console.log('S3 -> UPLOAD ERROR');
        console.log(e);
        cb_Work1({
            error: e
        });
    });

}
```

So here `Key` seems to be the file name.
But the thing is that I don't find yet detailed docs for `s3.putObject` so I don't know

1) how to specify a directory name (not just bucket name),
2) how to define permissions on that file which I am creating
3) how to create a sub-directory before putting the file, etc., etc., etc.

How can these things be done via `aws-sdk` (from JavaScript, node.js code)?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly the documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putObject-property). Secondly you misunderstand how S3 works. There are no folders/directories in S3 (although it provides the illusion of them); see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html

Comment: @404 this page says: `API Version: 2006-03-01` Are you sure this is recent?

Comment: Yes, it's the latest version. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html): "The current version of the Amazon S3 API is 2006-03-01"

Comment: @404 OK, then it seems like a very useful URL to bookmark. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the S3 documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/using-folders.html):

> The Amazon S3 console treats all objects that have a forward slash "/" character as the last (trailing) character in the key name as a folder, for example examplekeyname/. You cannot upload an object with a key name with a trailing "/" character by using the Amazon S3 console. **However, objects named with a trailing "/" can be uploaded with the Amazon S3 API by using the AWS CLI, the AWS SDKs, or REST API.**

As for permissions, the API provides the *putObjectAcl* function that allows defining an ACL to use when putting the object.

Answer (score 0):

The Key (filename) includes the full path of the object, eg:

```
folder1/folder2/test.txt
```

So, if you want to upload to a particular folder, just include the full path in the Key and it will work.

```
 Key: 'folder1/folder2/test.txt',
```

You can copy it to the folder that doesn't exist and the folder will be created for you. Then, if you delete the object the folder will be deleted because it never actually existed!